# Can you rewrite xml and add additional data via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to generate an XML file that i can import into Illustrator's variables dataset.

I receive an XML file from a website, looking like this.

```
<field-list>
 <field Id="spMF_1_6">
  <tag>Hårfarve</tag>
  <type>choice</type>
  <value>hair_red</value>
 </field>
</field-list>
```

I need to rewrite the XML and insert the "value" data from the original XML inside "sampleDataSet", so Illustrator will accept the file.

The finished file should look something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY ns_flows "http://ns.adobe.com/Flows/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_extend "http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_graphs "http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_vars "http://ns.adobe.com/Variables/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_custom "http://ns.adobe.com/GenericCustomNamespace/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_flows "http://ns.adobe.com/Flows/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_svg "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <!ENTITY ns_ai "http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_sfw "http://ns.adobe.com/SaveForWeb/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_adobe_xpath "http://ns.adobe.com/XPath/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_imrep "http://ns.adobe.com/ImageReplacement/1.0/">
]>
<svg version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
     x="0px" y="0px" width="0px" height="0px" viewBox="0 0 0 0" style="overflow:visible;" xml:space="preserve">
<variableSets  xmlns="&ns_vars;">
    <variableSet  locked="none" varSetName="binding1">
        <variables>
            <variable  category="&ns_vars;" trait="visibility" varName="hair_brown"></variable>
            <variable  category="&ns_vars;" trait="visibility" varName="hair_red"></variable>
            <variable  category="&ns_vars;" trait="visibility" varName="hair_blond"></variable>
        </variables>
        <v:sampleDataSets  xmlns="&ns_custom;" xmlns:v="&ns_vars;">
            <v:sampleDataSet  dataSetName="Datasæt 1">

               <hair_red>true</hair_red>

            </v:sampleDataSet>
        </v:sampleDataSets>
    </variableSet>
</variableSets>
</svg>
```

I don't know XML and XSLT well enough to know if this is possible or not, so i hope i can find the answer here.

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 1):

The only tricky part here is generating a document containing a DTD and entity references - XSLT doesn't support that directly. There are some extensions in products such as Saxon which might help, but you'll still need to do some post-processing. There was a product called Lexev from Andrew Welch as an XSLT plug-in to help processing XML with entity references, I don't know if it still works.

But basically, what you need to do is to generate the entity references in a form like `§ns_vars;` in place of `&ns_vars;`, and then post-process the serialised output to replace `§` by `&`.

Comment: I suspect a result that declares the namespaces using their actual URIs instead of entity references would also be acceptable.

Comment: Perhaps. If the OP had told us what part of the problem was proving challenging, then it would be easier to advise.